# How to fix Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am currently working on uploading the screenshot of React UI to the Azure blob storage.

But I have some issues when I upload the screenshot image.

Here is my part of codebase.

```
./src/captureError.js
export const getCapturedImageBlob = async (container) => {
    const screenshot = await html2canvas(container);
    return screenshot;
}

export const uploadImageToBlobStorage = (screenshot, connection_string, container_name, blob_name) => {
    screenshot.toBlob(blob => {
        console.log(blob);
        const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connection_string);
        const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container_name);
        const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob_name);

        blobClient.uploadData(blob);
    })
}
```

```
./src/App.js
const screenshot = await getCapturedImageBlob(document.querySelector("#root"));
    uploadImageToBlobStorage(screenshot, 'https://{Account Name}.blob.core.windows.net', {Container Name}, {Blob name});
```

Once I tried to upload the screenshot, I got this error.
[image]

```
PUT https://{Account Name}.blob.core.windows.net/{Container Name}/{Blob Name}?{Account Key} 401 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.)
```

Comment: Could you share the complete error message including the failing x-ms-request-ID that you received while executing the above code ?

Comment: @NaveenBaliga I just attached screenshot again on blog. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the error screenshot. Looking at the error details, it seems like you are uploading the blob using an incorrect request URL.

```
PUT https://{Account Name}.blob.core.windows.net/{Container Name}/{Blob Name}?{Account Key}
```

The above syntax is incorrect. Account Key shouldn't be passed as a query string. If you are using the SAS token to upload your blob, the syntax is as shown below:

[image]

More Information about the SAS token is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview). Please refer the sample code provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-javascript) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-typescript).

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question.
I also think passing account key is not correct.
But I also don't want to pass SAS token to the URL.
And I want to make my storage fully access from all users.
How can I do that? @NaveenBaliga.
Cors issue is already fixed now.

Comment: I also removed account key from my URL.
Now URL looks like this.
https://{Account Name}.blob.core.windows.net/{Container Name}/{Blob Name}.
But uploading also failed because of above issue.

Comment: Thanks NaveenBaliga.
I used SAS token and I can connect to Storage.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Storage allows only **authorized** PUT (Upload)operations.

The supported authorizations in Azure storage are mentioned below:

1. [Shared Key (storage account key)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key)
2. [Shared access signature (SAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) token.
3. [Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory)

If you don't want to use the SAS token, You need to use AAD RBAC permissions or use SharedKey to access the storage while performing the PUT operation.

Sample code is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/sdk/authentication/local-development-environment-service-principal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&tabs=azure-portal).